# jQuery flot - Zoom causes plot to shrink, axis labels to disappear

Tags: jquery, flot

I have implemented some zooming functionality with jQuery flot, but it is not working quite right. Zoom is implemented by capturing flot's "plotselected" event and re-plotting using the "ranges" parameter to modify the xaxis and yaxis max and min values.

The plot does show up correctly when it is initially plotted, and I can drag to make an x-y selection. When the plot is redrawn, the actual size of the axis grid on screen shrinks, though the appropriate data range is plotted. In addition, every time I zoom-replot, the axis labels disappear from view, though I can still see them in the inspector and there is some cruft in the extreme upper left of the plot that looks like the axis labels may have been moved up there and are partly (barely) visible. I have some other code that re-draws the plot with different data that also removes the axis labels from view, though the size of the plot doesn't shrink (as it does when zooming), and again the appropriate data are plotted. I mention that as perhaps the two issues share a common origin.

I thought perhaps I could take care of these problems by somehow destroying the plot or clearing the canvas before re-drawing, but I haven't found any guidance on how to do this.

Here are some relevant code snippets. The first lists the code which initially renders the plot and binds to the "plotselected" event:

```
            o.midGraph = $.plot($("#small-graph-mid"), testData, graphOptions);
                $("#small-graph-mid").unbind("plotselected");
                $("#small-graph-mid").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
                    graphOptions = o.midGraph.getOptions();
                    testData = o.midGraph.getData();
                    o.midGraph = $.plot($("#small-graph-mid"), testData,
                            self._graphZoomOptions(graphOptions, ranges));
                });
```

And here is the function that sets the axis extents to the new ranges:

```
    _graphZoomOptions: function(options, ranges) {
        return $.extend(true, {}, options, {
            xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to },
            yaxis: { min: ranges.yaxis.from, max: ranges.yaxis.to }
        });
    },
```

Am I on the right track in thinking that I need to somehow destroy/clear/reset the plot/canvas?

Comment: are you using any plugins? disable as many of them as you can while developing. Looking at your initialization code, it doesn't look like you are following the general plugin style outlined in the PLUGINS.txt file included in the FLOT zip file. Why not use the already included navigate plugin to achieve zooming and panning: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html

Answer (score 5):

Are you using jquery 1.7.2?

If so, take a look at [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=643#c4) and especially at the fixed navigation plugin that is included in comment #4.

It solved my problems with the navigation plugin after hours of messing around.

Comment: this is why the internet is awesome. had this exact issue and - someone's already fixed it and posted it for free and - someone else has asked the exact question on stack overflow and - someone has posted an answer linking to that exact solution! wins all around

Answer (score 1):

here's how I set my Y axes to a certain range. All Y axes will be set to the same range afterwards. 2 of the 4 statements in the "each" loop may be unnecessary, I just don't remember which ones.

```
$.each(yaxes, function(_, _yaxis){
    _yaxis.min = _min;
    _yaxis.max = _max;
    _yaxis.options.min=_min;
    _yaxis.options.max=_max;
});

setupGrid();
draw();
```

you shouldn't need to destroy the chart and redraw it. The setupGrid and draw functions handle that part for you.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem, resolved it by not using plot.getOptions().  Didn't look int to the cause of this but using the original options object I created when initiating the plot worked.